# Dishwasher wires twice

Tags: wiring, dishwasher

I removed my old dishwasher and found that it was wired to the wall and another wire ran behind a plug box under the sink. Why would there be two wires? And do I need to hook the new dishwasher up to both places?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: Why not just hook the new dishwasher exactly like the old one?

Answer (score 0):

The other wire could be for the disposal under sink.If never hooked up leave wires alone ,and wire nut them off if needed.  You had power to dishwasher hook up the same way